# Getting error java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '"' when making html table

Tags: java, html, html-table

I'm trying to write a send email program. I'm using html for the email template, but I get error:

> java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '"'

Here is the error and my code:

> java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '"'
>       java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
>       java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
>       java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
>       java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
>       java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
>
> id.jd.partnership.service.message.impl.SendingEmailServiceImpl.sendEmail(SendingEmailServiceImpl.java:86)

this is sendEmail line 86:

```
String contentResult = String.format(htmlText, customer.getName());
```

and here is the htmlText

```
String htmlText = "<img src=\"cid:Logo\" /><br><br>";
            htmlText += "<b> Dear %s, </b><br>";
            htmlText += "<p style='margin-bottom:1em;margin-top:1em;text-align:justify;'>Ini adalah email notifikasi untuk memberitahu Anda bahwa penukaran reward Samsung Slim Box Anda sudah kami terima. "
                    + "Kami sekarang akan menyiapkan barang Anda untuk pengiriman. "
                    + "Jangka waktu pengiriman yaitu 3 hari kerja untuk area Jabodetabek dan 7 hari kerja untuk area luar Jabodetabek. </p>";
            htmlText += "<p style='margin-bottom:1em;text-align:justify;'>Silahkan hubungi Tim Layanan Pelanggan kami jika Anda tidak dapat menerima paket di alamat pengiriman yang Anda berikan kepada kami, "
                    + "operator kami akan menghubungi Anda.</p> ";
            htmlText += "<p style='margin-bottom:1em;text-align:justify;'>Kunjungi Pusat Bantuan kami jika Anda ingin memahami lebih lanjut tentang Pengiriman. "
                    + "Ingat, Tim Layanan Pelanggan kami siap untuk membantu Anda dengan pertanyaan yang berkaitan dengan pesanan Anda, "
                    + "cukup email kami di cs@jd.id. </p>";
            htmlText += "<p style='margin-bottom:1em;'>Hormat Kami,<br>PT Jingdong Indonesia Pertama<br>www.jd.id</p>";
            htmlText += "<p style='font-family; Helvetica, Arial; color: #7f8c8d; font-size:12px; text-align:justify;'><b>Kebijakan Privasi dan Keamanan<br></b></p>";
            htmlText += "<p style='font-family; Helvetica, Arial; color: #7f8c8d; font-size:12px; text-align:justify;'>JD tidak akan pernah meminta anda untuk memberi tahu kata sandi atau informasi akun pribadi anda kepada kami melalui email "
                    + "Anda hanya akan diminta untuk memasukkan password anda ketika anda masuk ke website kami. Kami menggunakan langkah-langkah untuk memastikan keamanan anda berbelanja di website kami dan melindungi kerahasiaan informasi pribadi yang anda berikan kepada kami. "
                    + "Kami juga melakukan segala upaya untuk memastikan email-email yang kami kirimkan telah melalui proses pengecekan virus sebelum dikirimkan. "
                    + "Jika anda menerima email yang mencurigakan atau terjadi kesalahan tujuan pengiriman, mohon laporkan hal tersebut kepada Tim Layanan Pelanggan kami di contact cs@jd.id untuk penyelidikan lebih lanjut.</font></p>";
            htmlText += "<table width=\"100% \"cellpading=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
            htmlText += "<tr>";
            htmlText += "<td align=center>";
            htmlText += "<p style='font-family; Helvetica, Arial; color: #7f8c8d; font-size:12px; text-align:center;'>Ikuti kami:<a href=\"facebook.com/JDID\"><img src=\"cid:fb\"/><a href=\"twitter.com/JDID\"><img src=\"cid:twitter\"/><a href=\"instagram.com/JDID\"><img src=\"cid:instagram\"/></a>";
            htmlText += "</td></tr>";
            htmlText += "<tr><td align=center>";
            htmlText += "<p style='font-family; Helvetica, Arial; font-size:12px; text-align:center;'>Copyright © 2015-2016 jd.id Ltd. All Rights Reserved</p>";
            htmlText += "</td> </tr></table>";
```

Actually everything works fine, until I add the html table in this code:

```
htmlText += "<table width=`100%` cellpading=`0` cellspacing=`0`>".replace('`', '"');
            htmlText += "<tr>";
            htmlText += "<td align=center>";
            htmlText += "<p style='font-family; Helvetica, Arial; color: #7f8c8d; font-size:12px; text-align:center;'>Ikuti kami:<a href=\"facebook.com/JDID\"><img src=\"cid:fb\"/><a href=\"twitter.com/JDID\"><img src=\"cid:twitter\"/><a href=\"instagram.com/JDID\"><img src=\"cid:instagram\"/></a>";
            htmlText += "</td></tr>";
            htmlText += "<tr><td align=center>";
            htmlText += "<p style='font-family; Helvetica, Arial; font-size:12px; text-align:center;'>Copyright © 2015-2016 jd.id Ltd. All Rights Reserved</p>";
            htmlText += "</td> </tr></table>";
```

I hope you understand from what I'm saying. Please help.

Comment: It might be some thing to do with `width=100%` in your `table` tag. `%` should be escaped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the percentage symbol in your table tag like this:

```
htmlText += "<table width=`100%%` cellpading=`0` cellspacing=`0`>".replace('`', '"');
```

`String.format` uses `%` to format data. So to escape it, you need to use `%%`.

[Refer to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) on `Formatter`.

---

Hope this helps!